# vuejs show default image if no imagedata is found for 2 properties

Tags: vue.js

I am using vuejs. I am having difficulty displaying the default image if the two properties (selImage and imageData are empty). Is there a better way to write this. I can achieve it if its only one, but not both. I would prefer not to use computed in this case. any help. Thanks

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    path: `https://example.com/`,
    selImage: '',
    imageData: '',

  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <img v-if="selImage" :src="path+selImage" />
  <img v-else-if="imageData" :src="imageData" />
  <img src="example.com/myimage.jpg" v-show="!selImage || !imageData" />


</div>
```

Comment: how would they be empty? instead of `v-show="!selImage || !imageData"` use just `v-else`, though a nicer way would to put the logic in a computed prop and then you only have one <img> tag

Comment: so if you see updated code....i removed the data for selImage and imageData. So since niether contain data---the default image would appear. how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is what worked best in my case.

```html
<img v-if="selImage" :src="path+selImage" />
                <img v-else-if="imageData" :src="imageData" />
                <img  v-else src="example.com/myimage.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create computed property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      path: `https://example.com/`,
      selImage: '',
      imageData: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getImg() {
      if(!this.selImage && !this.imageData) return 'https://picsum.photos/200'
      return this.selImage ? this.path + this.selImage : this.path + this.imageData
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <img :src="getImg" />
</div>
```

Comment: is there another away instead of using computed for this..

Comment: @Vzupo hey mate, I think doing this with computed property is better/cleaner then with showing/hiding dom elements :)